# Pass binding from parent to child view conforming to UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

I need to rely on a `PageView` view that has a `currentPage` value, in such a way that the `PageView` itself has ownership of the value (therefore, `@State`) but I need to update *app state* when this value changes.

With `TabView`, I simply put `@Binding` `$selected` in as an argument and can act upon changes to this value outside of the UI layer using a custom `Binding<Int>` with my own getter and setter. That is the method I'm trying right now to put together a solution.

But my `PageView` is based on an array of `UIHostingControllers` and a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to integrate `UIPageViewController` from UIKit (I know that Swift in 5.3 will offer the SwiftUI version through TabView, but I don't want to wait until "September")

> PageViewController.swift

```
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388071/how-to-implement-pageview-in-swiftui

struct PageViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var controllers: [UIViewController]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
                transitionStyle: .scroll,
                navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        if controllers.count > 0 {
            pageViewController.setViewControllers([controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            self.parent = pageViewController
        }

        func pageViewController(
                _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return parent.controllers.last
            }
            return parent.controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
                _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == parent.controllers.count {
                return parent.controllers.first
            }
            return parent.controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
               let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
               let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                    parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> PageView.swift

```
struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]

    var currentPage: Binding<Int>

    init(_ views: [Page], currentPage: Binding<Int>) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map {
            let ui = UIHostingController(rootView: $0)
            ui.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return ui
        }

        self.currentPage = currentPage
    }

    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: currentPage)
                PageControl(numberOfPages: viewControllers.count, currentPage: currentPage)
            }.frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Above you can see I'm trying passing in a `Binding<Int>` argument from the parent view, `PageViewTest`

> PageViewTest.swift

```
struct PageViewTest: View {
    var pagesData = ["ONE", "TWO"]
    var _currentPage: Int = 0
    
    var currentPage: Binding<Int> {
        Binding<Int>(get: {
            self._currentPage
        }, set: {
            // i.e. Update app state
            print($0)
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PageView(pagesData.map {
                Text($0)
            }, currentPage: self.currentPage)
        }
    }
}
```

This set up works as far as calling the setter routine specified in PageViewTest, but for some reason the binding is not reflected in the `PageControl` (from PageView.swift) that conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` so I don't feel like this is THE solution.

Am I passing around the bindings incorrectly? The PageView should own the state of `currentPage`, but I want its ancestor view to be able to act on changes to it.

@ObservableObject won't work because I just want to send a primitive. `CurrentValueSubject`/`Passthrough` won't fire (presumably because the PageView is being reinitialized over and over):

> Alternative PageView.swift

```
struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]

    var valStr = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    @State var currentPage: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            valStr.send(currentPage)
        }
    }

    init(_ views: [Page], _ cb: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map {
            let ui = UIHostingController(rootView: $0)
            ui.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return ui
        }

        valStr.sink(receiveValue: { value in
            cb(value)
        }).store(in: &store)
    }

    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
                PageControl(numberOfPages: viewControllers.count, currentPage: $currentPage)
            }.frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: This topic [SwiftUI scrollViewDidScroll in UIPageViewController not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621677/swiftui-scrollviewdidscroll-in-uipageviewcontroller-not-work-properly) should be helpful

Comment: @Asperi thank you for the link. I have spent some time with this and still haven't solved it. I'm zooming out from this for now and will revisit it later.